# Qt how to check which mouse button is pressed

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have problems in PySide while trying to determine which mouse button is pressed in event function. I need it in particular for ignoring mouse move event, because it's doing job on both mouse buttons, left and right.

I want to ignore mouse move event if the right button on scene is pressed. Any help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All of mouse events have two methods (`button` and `buttons`) to determine which of buttons are pressed. But for only `move` event the documentation says:

> Note that the returned value is always Qt::NoButton for mouse move events.

for `mouseMoveEvent` you should use `buttons` method.

```
void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if(e->buttons() == Qt::RightButton)
        qDebug() << "Only right button";
}
```

In order to ignore move events you need to do this work in `eventFilter` of course.

Comment: That's what I need. Thank you so much. I would open new question for eventFilter if you can help me with mouse filtering.

Comment: @Alex you're welcome, I will see your question about `eventFilter` as soon as possible, but I am able to provide you C++ code only.

Comment: Posted HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16772227/qt-mouse-event-propagation-with-scene-items

Answer (score 14):

`QApplication::mouseButtons()` will return the status of `mouseButton`,
so, you can get the status of mouse in `KeyPressEvent`.

Comment: To me it seems that this answer doesn't match OPs question well. Nevertheless, it answers perfectly my question for which I have just googled and found this Q/A. :-)

Answer (score 2):

you can check, which mouse button is pressed via `Qt::RightButton`. Sorry for c++ code, but i hope, you would understand idea anyway:

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{ 
    if (event->button()==Qt::RightButton){
        qDebug() << "right button is pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: Vote up for your engagement, but I already tried this, and while it works with mouse press and mouse release, it not works in MOUSE MOVE event.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The widget receives `QContextMenuEvent` instead of `QMouseEvent` no matter what I do - even though I have no menu, and trying to use `setContextMenuPolicy` doesn't change a thing.

Comment: You have to use `.buttons()` (note the 's') on mouseMoveEvents as `.button()` will always return Qt::NoButton for this event. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#button

Answer (score 2):

You could use a boolean:

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{ 
if (event->button()==Qt::RightButton){
    qDebug() << "right button is pressed
    pressed=true; //<-----
}
}
```

and on mouseMoveEvent

```
void GLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{

float dx = event->x() - lastPos.x();      // where lastpos is a QPoint member
float dy = event->y() - lastPos.y();

if (dx<0) dx=-dx;
if (dy<0) dy=-dy;

if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {  //if you have MOVEd

     ...do something

}

if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {

    if (pressed==true) return;  
    else{
    ...do   
    } 
}
}
```

On mouserelease you have to set pressed=false; ( "pressed" must be a member of the class)

Hope it helps,let me know

Comment: +1 for try, but it's not what I need. I wouldn't put boolean for that matter, too risky when user is clumsy with mouse...have noticed that Qt is not the very best with mouse event processing. I am assured that there's built-in method for that purpose.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly, it only seemed to pickup the mouse button if the statement read: `if (event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)` for example, rather than `button()`.