# Qt Call function in main class from qlabel click event

Tags: c++, qt

I have a main class like this

```cpp
class ImagePuzzle : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ImagePuzzle(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ImagePuzzle();

private:
    QVector<QVector<ClickableLabel*> > imageLabelArray;
};
```

In order to create a click event for the labels I followed this doc: https://wiki.qt.io/Clickable_QLabel and make a class like this:

```cpp
class ClickableLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClickableLabel(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    ~ClickableLabel();
    void setId (int id);

signals:
    void clicked();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

private:
    int id;
};
```

How do I call a function in ImagePuzzle from ClickableLabel::mousePressEvent with the ClickableLabel::id passed as argument?

[Edited] Following the suggestions I add a signal, but it is not working. (can compiled but do not call the function in main class)
clickablelabel.h

```
class ClickableLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClickableLabel(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    ~ClickableLabel();
    void setId (int id);

signals:
//    static void clicked();
    void test (int id);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

private:
    int id;
};
```

clickablelabel.cpp

```
void ClickableLabel::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event) {
//    emit clicked();
    emit test(id);
}

void ClickableLabel::setId (int id) {
    this->id = id;
}
```

imagepuzzle.h

```
class ImagePuzzle : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ImagePuzzle(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ImagePuzzle();

public slots:
  void test(int id);

private:

    Ui::ImagePuzzle *ui;
    QVector<QVector<ClickableLabel*> > imageLabelArray;
};
```

imagepuzzle.cpp

```
void ImagePuzzle::test (int id) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: In mouse press event when the desired button is pressed you emit clicked(); Then use the clicked signal like you would any other signal. This should help for how you detect what button is pressed: [https://stackoverflow.com/q/16759544/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16759544/487892)

Comment: More precisely, every element in the label vector has their own id. If there is a variable sum in the ImagePuzzle class. How can I add the id to the ImagePuzzle::sum every time I click a label.

Comment: You need to change the signal to take a parameter then and emit that signal with the parameter. Perhaps `void labelClicked( int id)` then in your mousePressEvent `emit labelClicked(id)`

Comment: Multiple solutions exist: 
1. passing the `ImagePuzzle` object to `ClickableLabel` in the constructor
2. using signal and slot to connect `clicked` with a slot in `ImagePuzzle` 
3. ...

Comment: which one would you recommend?

Comment: @drescherjm how can I declare labelClicked in the main class and use it in the label class?

Comment: You declare this instead of clicked() in the label class. In ImagePuzzle you would have a slot that has the same 1 parameter.

Comment: You may want to edit your question to add the additional information. Your original question did not make it clear that you wanted the `id` to be known in `ImagePuzzle` when the slot was executed.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you for pointing out the problem i also added my current code

Comment: Where do you connect your signal to slot? This will not happen automatically for you. You need to iterate through your `imageLabelArray` and connect each signal to your test slot in `ImagePuzzle`

Comment: Thanks, since I do not know about slots and signals,  I'm going to read some docs and come back later.

Comment: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Answer (score 1):

Following @drescherjm suggestion and reading https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html, I got a signals & slots solution:

clickablelabel.h

```
class ClickableLabel : public QLabel {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ClickableLabel(QWidget* parent = Q_NULLPTR, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags());
    ~ClickableLabel();
    void setId (int id);

signals:
    void test (int id);

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);

private:
    int id;
};
```

imagepuzzle.h

```
class ImagePuzzle : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ImagePuzzle(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~ImagePuzzle();

private slots:
  void test(int id);

};
```

by connecting the signals and slots in somewhere

```
connect(curLabel, &ClickableLabel::test, this, &ImagePuzzle::test);
```

I am able to communicate with the main class using this

```
emit test(id);
```

What a wonderful day :)